# Translation Golf XLVI - The Bard's Song (In the Forest)

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> **Game finished.** The winner is walen with [a proposal of just 195 characters](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30539/12637) and *asonante* rhyme. User blonfu came up with [a proposal of the same length](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/30538/12637) but failed to rhyme the first two verses.

---

Welcome to a new edition of the game! If this is your first time, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

Following are the first verses of one of the most popular songs by the [power metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_metal) band [Blind Guardian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_Guardian), [*The Bard's Song - In the Forest*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChOMlcqk_2U):

> Now you all know
>   The bards and their songs
>   When hours have gone by
>   I'll close my eyes
>   In a world far away
>   We may meet again
>   But now hear my song
>   About the dawn of the night
>   Let's sing the bards' song
>
> Tomorrow will take us away
>   Far from home
>   No one will ever know our names
>   But the bards' songs will remain
>   Tomorrow will take it away
>   The fear of today
>   It will be gone
>   Due to our magic songs
>
> <sub>(304 characters)</sub>

---

The goal is to translate the given text to Spanish, using as few letters as possible, while keeping all the original text's meaning and concepts more or less intact.

My own, non-golfed translation:

> Ahora conocéis
>  A los bardos y sus canciones
>  Cuando hayan pasado las horas
>  Cerraré mis ojos
>  En un mundo distante
>  Podríamos volver a vernos
>  Por ahora, oíd mi canción
>  Sobre el amanecer de la noche
>  Cantemos la canción del bardo
>
>  El mañana nos llevará
>  Lejos de casa
>  Nadie conocerá nunca nuestros nombres
>  Pero las canciones de los bardos perdurarán
>  El mañana se llevará
>  Los miedos de hoy
>  Se irán
>  Gracias a la magia de nuestras canciones
>
>  <sub>(313 characters)</sub>

Remember that every word and concept that appear in the original text must also appear in the translation. I'll check with special care the following:

- The references to the bards and their songs.
- The chance of meeting again in the future.
- Let's sing the bard's song.
- The bard's songs being the only thing that remains when all the other things are gone.
- The healing ability of the bard's songs.

---

General rules for this game are as follows:

- Rules: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- **Rhyme bonus**: if you are up for a challenge, make your translation rhyme to get a **10% discount bonus** in your total char count!

  - The rhyming in this song seems to be a bit loose, so this time you can create your own rhyming as long as there are 16 verses rhyming of a total of 17 verses in the original song. Just state in your answer which verses are the ones rhyming.
  - You can still get a **5% discount** if your rhyming is *asonante*.

Also, remember that not every character counts for the total: only letters and numbers do. You can paste your translation in the letter counter linked below to obtain your char count.

- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contestants? Join us in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 195 caracteres

> Saben ya
>   de bardos y sus tonos
>   Horas tras,
>   cerraré mis ojos.
>   En mundo lejano
>   revernos podremos.
>   Mas ya del ocaso
>   oye mi canto.
>   El del bardo
>   cantemos.
>
> Cras
>   ajenos
>   de la gente y el lar
>   mas el son quedará.
>   El miedo
>   de hoy
>   cras se irá
>   por nueso mágico son.

Rima asonante, `ababcdcccd adaadeae`.
Recordemos que en los diptongos se considera que existe asonancia cuando la vocal tónica es la misma ([Wikipedia: Rima](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rima)), por tanto *hoy* rima con *son*.

Comment: ¡Eres el ganador! Tienes 48 horas para plantear un nuevo reto o ceder el turno a quien quieras.

Answer (score 4):

#### 326 caracteres

> Conocen ahora
>   las canciones bardas.
>   Cuando pase la hora
>   mis pupilas estarán cerradas.
>
> En mundos que distantes
>   nuestras almas reencontradas
>   pero escucha mis cantares
>   del amanecer nocturno.
>   Cantemos las canciones bardas.
>
> El mañana nos llevará
>   de casa muy lejos.
>   Los nombres olvidará
>   pero quedarán las canciones bardas.
>   El mañana se llevará
>   el miedo del hoy
>   se irá
>   por nuestras canciones mágicas.

Answer (score 4):

#### <strike>271</strike> 195

> Ya sabéis
>   de cantos de vates
>   después
>   los ojos cerraré
>   en un orbe lejano
>   quizá nos veamos
>   oye mi canto
>   del alba nocturna
>   dale al aire de los bardos
>
> Estaremos
>   tan lejos
>   ignotos
>   quedará el tono
>   mañana
>   el miedo acaba
>   se irá
>   con el mágico cantar

---

<sub>Rima de versos consecutivos en asonante, salvo el verso 6 que rima con el 8 y el 7 queda libre</sub>

Comment: he usado el mismo argumento tuyo que cuando hay diptongo se puede rimar solo con la vocal fuerte, cosa de la que no tenía ni idea

Comment: @walen oh, es verdad, pues me he colado ahí. Por otra parte mi respuesta de la rima era sobre otra cosa, aunque la verdad que no me acordaba de eso y lo aprendí en aquella pregunta